# How to show data after query from Bottle Framework with angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: python, angularjs, templates, bottle

My data from Bottle Framework after query:  `{{rows}}`

> [(1, 'Crystal', 'Daklak', 1995, 'IT'), (2, 'Trace', 'Hue', 1995, 'IT'), (3, 'Tina', 'Ha Tinh', 1995, 'IT'), (4, 'Na', 'Da Nang', 1995, 'IT')]

When I use `ng-repeat` to show them as a table:

```
     {% raw %}
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ng-init="data=rows">
            <td>
                {{row[0]}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{row[1]}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{row[2]}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{row[3]}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{row[4]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endraw %}
```

And I receive the error like this:

> NameError: name 'row' is not defined

I know this error occurred when Bottle read  `{{expression}}` in template, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller that is controlling this template/partial, you need to have `$scope.data` containing results.

```
angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('ctrlname', ['$scope', 'myservice',  function($scope,myservice){

    $scope.data = myservice.getData();

   }]

   .service('myservice', ['$http', function($http){

        var self = this;

        //query your endpoint.
        self.getData = function(){
            return $http.get('url').then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
        }

        return {
            getData: function(){
                 return self.getData();
            }
        }

   }]
```

In your template. Always better if you use object references inside your ng-repeat instead of array indices.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
    <td>
        {{row[0]}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{row[1]}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{row[2]}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{row[3]}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{row[4]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still in trouble.
In Bottle, I return values to `rows`, and I use `@route('/table)'`, then I follow your code and change `url` to `http://localhost:8080/table`. 
That error still appears.

Comment: I would suggest converting what you are doing in Bottle to an API endpoint, query that endpoint from the service mentioned in the code snippet above and then use the service inside controller for binding. That should work

Comment: Is there anyway else when I received data from backend like that? Why we have to push the data to API endpoint, then query again? Why don't directly use it?
I have just learned angularjs and bottle a few days ago.

Comment: To pass data back and forth, you should really employ either an API using ajax calls or a websocket connection.